# Проблема стилизации input в выпадающем списке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

При выборе пункта из меню, в инпуте появляется такая вот фигня. Как её стилизовать?

P.S. уверен что дело в скрипте

```
$('.slct').click(function(){
    /* Заносим выпадающий список в переменную */
    var dropBlock = $(this).parent().find('.drop');

    /* Делаем проверку: Если выпадающий блок скрыт то делаем его видимым*/
    if( dropBlock.is(':hidden') ) {
        dropBlock.slideDown(1);

        /* Выделяем ссылку открывающую select */
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).find('.slct').parent('.slct').parent().addClass('styling_slct');

        /* Работаем с событием клика по элементам выпадающего списка */
        $('.drop').find('li').click(function(){

            /* Заносим в переменную HTML код элемента
            списка по которому кликнули */
            var selectResult = $(this).html();

            /* Находим наш скрытый инпут и передаем в него
            значение из переменной selectResult */
            $(this).parent().parent().find('input').val(selectResult);

            /* Передаем значение переменной selectResult в ссылку которая
            открывает наш выпадающий список и удаляем активность */
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.slct').removeClass('active').html(selectResult);

            /* Скрываем выпадающий блок */
            dropBlock.slideUp(10);
        });

    /* Продолжаем проверку: Если выпадающий блок не скрыт то скрываем его */
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        dropBlock.slideUp(1);
    }

    /* Предотвращаем обычное поведение ссылки при клике */
    return false;
});
```

Comment: А html и css где?

Comment: html  <div class="select">
                <div class="pattern_triangle"></div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slct">Няня</a>
                <ul class="drop">
                <div class="first_layer">
                <div class="second_layer"></div></div>
                    <li><a href="#">Гувернантка</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Дворник</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Водитель</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Садовник</a></li>
                </ul>
                <input type="hidden" id="select"/>
            </div>